# How do I run ordered integrated-test on Maven?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, selenium-rc

How do I run ordered integrated-tests on Maven? I'd like to run the tests in this order:

1. Login.java
2. checkbase.java
3. blah.java
4. Logout.java

It currently runs in alphabetically order, I'd rather not rename the files for testing. I'm using JUnit

Thanks!

Comment: What framework are you using ? Junit, TestNG or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the failsafe plugin for running your integration tests, you can specify the order in which the tests will be run by specifying the [runOrder](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#runOrder) parameter, which is valid after version 2.7. From the documentation:

> Defines the order the tests will be run in. Supported values are
>   "alphabetical", "reversealphabetical", "random", "hourly"
>   (alphabetical on even hours, reverse alphabetical on odd hours) and
>   "filesystem". Odd/Even for hourly is determined at the time the of
>   scanning the classpath, meaning it could change during a multi-module
>   build. Default: filesystem

So there isn't any way to specify that tests are run in an arbitrary order. If you use TestNG however, you can specify the order.

If you're using the surefire plugin, you have exactly the same parameter, [runOrder](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder), with the same values possible.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I'll look into TestNG

Comment: FYI: runOrder-failedfirst is only supported from failsafe version 2.11